# Use RSelenium to select a state in a drop down with changing link name

Tags: r, rselenium

I am still pretty new to using RSelenium but I have been able to stumble my way through a few problems I am stuck on a webscraping project that I am trying to get through drop-down menus that seem to change their link names every time I reload the site.

The website has a login for clients so I can't give the URL but I will do my best to describe what it is doing.

I have a list of states and counties that I need to search in the drop-down and I use

```
agsearch <- remDr$findElement(using = "p",value="RE AGENT RANK")
agsearch$clickElement()

Stsearch <- remDr$findElement(using = "xpath",value='//*[(@id = "select2-state_bs_avg-container")]')
Stsearch$clickElement()
```

That lets me select the dropdown list but now selecting a state in the list changes each time

```
<li class="select2-results__option select2-results__option--highlighted" id="select2-state_bs_avg-result-nqb3-KS" role="treeitem" aria-selected="true" data-select2-id="select2-state_bs_avg-result-nqb3-CO">Colarado</li>
```

and I have found it using

```
StDrop <- remDr$findElement(using = "id", value = "select2-state_bs_avg-result-nqb3-CO")
StDrop$clickElement()
```

the problem is the "nqb3" in the id changes every time I reload to a different state or county to a different combo of numbers and letters.  is there a way that I can search for this by just the state name or the last two digits?

Thank You